# Is there a CSS counter equivalent for list-style-type?

Tags: css, css-counter

CSS has a nice collection of values for `list-style-type`, Is there a way to use them as the value of `content: counter(steps)`?

I want to use `list-style-type: persian` in counter value.

Result would be:

```
۱ // (one)
۲ // (two)
۳ // (three)
۴ // (four)
۵ // (five)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [`counter()` function takes the style type as a parameter](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#counter-functions). The syntax is as given below:

> counter()  =  counter( <ident> [, [ <counter-style> | none ] ]? )

```css
body {
  counter-reset: divs;
}
div {
  counter-increment: divs;
}
div:before {
  content: counter(divs, persian);
}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
```

Comment: `-moz-persian` can also be added to support Mozilla Firefox, Documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type#Values